# Sandbox Test Account : IAP - No 'Transaction Response From Apple' Received

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I am testing my In-App Purchase code. I am presented with the following dialogue in the Xcode console:

Transaction is initiated:

```
About to fetch the products
```

Checks if user can make payments:

```
User can make purchases and will fetch products from Apple Store now
```

Product(s) exist and are retrieved from Apple servers ...

```
Full Access To xxxxxx xxxxx xxxx (my product description)
Sending the Payment Request to Apple
Received Payment Transaction Response from Apple
```

And transaction is stuck here. NO response from Apple servers received.

I have read a lot of content that states sandbox accounts testing is often riddled with bugs.

Is this one of them?

I have played around a lot with sandbox testing accounts and have never been presented with this particular situation.

Is anyone able to shed any light on the situation for me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My IAP code works now on my test device.

What I did was:

1. Perform a soft reset of my device; and
2. Completed some app updates that had not completed under my 'normal' Apple ID.

The combination of the two steps resolved my inability to receive a `Payment Transaction Response`.